# Add a column if exists to the sql table and populate it

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a column if it doesn't exist and populate it. My query is the following

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
        FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
            WHERE
                TABLE_SCHEMA = 'table_name'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'adapter'
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'adapter_ip'
)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE `adapter` ADD `adapter_ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '192.168.194.57';
    UPDATE `adapter` SET `adapter_ip` = '192.168.194.57';
END;
```

Yet every time I get an error. What exactly am I doing wrong? I tested and if I run

```
    SELECT *
        FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
            WHERE
                TABLE_SCHEMA = 'table_name'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'adapter'
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'adapter_ip'
```

by itself then it works. As soon as I put it into the if statement it gives me error at line 1 saying syntax is wrong. Because of that I even tried replacing `BEGIN` with `THEN`, and that didn't work either. Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks to anyone for their help.

Comment: @JonH The problem is that I have tried replacing BEGIN with THEN and END with END IF and yet every time I get an error saying wrong syntax on line 1, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a `THEN`, and an `END IF` after your `IF <condition>`

Also, this link looks good: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mysql/howto_add_column_unless_exists.htm

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for IF is if(test-expr,then-expr,else-expr), as detailed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html